# Convert tabbed text into tree (SQL insert each line into TreeNode table (TreeNodeID, ParentID, Title)) with PHP

Tags: php, database, automation, screen-scraping, arbor.js

I'm experimenting with ArborJS, attempting to build a Knowledge Tree. [Here](http://atr.eng.utah.edu/~lwilkins/arborTest/KT1/index.html) is my test area (left click to enter a node, right click to get back to the beginning). I have "all" of the "Humanities and the Arts" section fleshed out, so I suggest playing through that area.

I'm building this tree from [Wikipedia's List of Academic Disciplines article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_academic_disciplines).

Now, I am pulling data from one mySQL table (via PHP). The table structure is TreeNodeID, ParentID, Title. The "TreeNodeID" is the primary key (autoincrementing), "ParentID" is the node's parent, the "Title" is the text that should be displayed on the node.

I'm now on page 7 of 27 on this article. I feel like I'm not taking advantage of my computer's ability to automate this process of typing in manually.

I just made a text file of all the subjects. It's in the the following format:

```
Anthropology
    Biological Anthropology
        Forensic Anthropology
        Gene-Culture Coevolution
        Human Behavioral Ecology
    Anthropological Linguistics
        Synchronic Linguistics
        Diachronic Linguistics
        Ethnolinguistics
        Socioloinguistics
    Cultural Anthropology
        Anthropology of Religion
        Economic Anthropology
Archaelogy
...
```

How can I use PHP to go through this and fill my database (with the correct ParentIDs for each node)?

UPDATE #3: The working code (given by correct answer below)

```
<?php
//echo "Checkpoint 1";

$data = "
Social sciences
    Anthropology
        Biological anthropology
            Forensic anthropology
            Gene-culture coevolution
            Human behavioral ecology
            Human evolution
            Medical anthropology
            Paleoanthropology
            Population genetics
            Primatology
        Anthropological linguistics
            Synchronic linguistics (or Descriptive linguistics)
            Diachronic linguistics (or Historical linguistics)
            Ethnolinguistics
            Sociolinguistics
        Cultural anthropology
            Anthropology of religion
            Economic anthropology
            Ethnography
            Ethnohistory
            Ethnology
            Ethnomusicology
            Folklore
            Mythology
            Political anthropology
            Psychological anthropology
    Archaeology
        ...(goes on for a long time)
";

//echo "Checkpoint 2\n";

$lines = preg_split("/\n/", $data);

$parentids = array(0 => null);
$db = new PDO("host", 'username', 'pass');
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `TreeNode` SET ParentID = ?, Title = ?';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

//echo "Checkpoint 3\n";

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (!preg_match('/^([\s]*)(.*)$/', $line, $m)) {
        continue;
    }
    $spaces = strlen($m[1]);
    //$level = intval($spaces / 4); //assumes four spaces per indent
    $level = strlen($m[1]); // if data is tab indented
    $title = $m[2];
    $parentid = ($level > 0 ? $parentids[$level - 1] : 1); //All "roots" are children of "Academia" which has an ID of "1";

    $rv = $stmt->execute(array($parentid, $title));

    $parentids[$level] = $db->lastInsertId();
    echo "inserted $parentid - " . $parentid . " title: " . $title . "\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: @RossSmithII I'm looking at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601349/read-a-text-file-and-transfer-contents-to-mysql-database but, I don't know how to keep the parent-child relationships

Comment: If I were able to get it into an associative array (of associative arrays of ...). How could I get the TreeNodeID of the parent, with only the title, assuming that the title isn't always unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but this should work for you (uses PDO):

```
<?php

$data = "
Anthropology
    Biological Anthropology
        Forensic Anthropology
        Gene-Culture Coevolution
        Human Behavioral Ecology
    Anthropological Linguistics
        Synchronic Linguistics
        Diachronic Linguistics
        Ethnolinguistics
        Socioloinguistics
    Cultural Anthropology
        Anthropology of Religion
        Economic Anthropology
Archaelogy
";

$lines = preg_split("/\n/", $data);

$parentids = array(0 => null);

$sql = 'INSERT INTO `table` SET ParentID = ?, Title = ?';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (!preg_match('/^([\s]*)(.*)$/', $line, $m)) {
        continue;
    }
    #$spaces = strlen($m[1]);
    #$level = intval($spaces / 4); # if data is space indented
    $level = strlen($m[1]); # assumes data is tab indented
    $title = $m[2];

    $parentid = $level > 0
        ? $parentids[$level - 1]
        null;

    $rv = $stmt->execute(array($parentid, $title));

    $parentids[$level] = $db->lastInsertId();
}
```

Comment: Just a few improvements: (1) I would use `/^([\s]*)(.*)$/` it should work the same way, but it explicitly tells next guy to read this that you are going to catch everything up to the end of the string; (2) you can use `$parentid=$parentids[$level]` without check because you have already set `$parentids[0]` to null.

Comment: Nice! Going to give this a go

Comment: @JOHN, I added (1). I think (2) is not correct, when `$level` is 0, we always want to set `$parentid` to `null`, but when `$level` is 1, we want `$parentid` to be set to `$parentids[0]`, so I think `$parentids = array(0 => null);` should really be just `$parentids = array();`, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it's easier to **copy-paste** to a text file first, **indenting** as you have done above. Then parse it:

- read each line (one at a time), gives you the node text.
- each indent is a new child so the prev node is the parent id
- check for dedents - count `\t`'s if you've been consistent or keep a count of `indent level`. Watch out for 0-indent (roots).

This will allow you to build an **associative array** containing each of the disciplines. Then you **interpret** that. For example:

- Get all the root nodes (1st child of root, depending) and give them an incremental id **`parse_id`**.
- Continue along the array from above, assigning `parse_id`s to all nodes.
- Then start putting that data into MySQL. As you do, add `mysqli_insert_id` in the array along with `parse_id`, calling **`db_id`** for example. That should be used to associate the `parent_id` required in the db with the parent's `parse_id`.

Assuming  you are not trying to check for common studies or unique node text, that should be straightforward enough.

Comment: PS: It might be even easier to - get the data into text using tabs to indicate children. Then paste that into excel or similar (sorry) with tabs as delimiters. That would give you each parent and child in a diff column, with blank cells at the child rows (1 cell per row). Then auto-fill each rows left-side columns. Would get your data into a db faster but completely UN-normalized and probably more inconvenient to get in the right structure later.

Comment: Alright, so I understand up til the second part, where this parse_id and mysqli_insert_id business. I'm going to get the associative array up and running real quick and then see if I can figure out the second part (see edit soon)

Comment: @Silver The parse_id should be generated by you while you create the nested associative arrays. That way, you have a way of mapping the parent_id of each node.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with the following

```
// parser.php

<?php
include_once './vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

$crawler = new Crawler(file_get_contents('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_academic_disciplines'));

$texts = $crawler->filter('.tocnumber + .toctext');
$numbers = $crawler->filter('.tocnumber');


$last = '';

for ($i=0; $i < count($numbers); $i++) {
    $value = $numbers->eq($i)->text();
    if(!preg_match('/\d+.\d+/', $value)) {
        // is a root discipline
        $last = $texts->eq($i)->text();
    } else {
        // is a leaf discipline
        $disciplines[$last][$texts->eq($i)->text()] = $texts->eq($i)->text();
    }
}

var_dump($disciplines);
```

with this you can do some more like persist in database or any and is useful for others DOM parsing tasks

i used CssSelector and DomCrawler from Symfony Components is easy to install

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "wiki-parser",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.1.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.1.0"
    }
}
```

in the console

```
$ php composer.phar install
```

take a look for [getcomposer](http://getcomposer.org/)