# How to transfer data from multiple .txt files into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem regarding transfering data from a .txt file to my database. I have 10 .txt files and would like to transfer all its data to my database. The code below is what i was trying so far for just one .txt file. its giving errors. when the person click on upload, i upload the zip file to the server in the folder uploads. the code that does this works and is the following:

```
if(isset($_FILES['zip'])){
    $errors = array();

    $zip = new ZipArchive();

    if(strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['zip']['name'])))!=='zip'){
        $errors[] = 'That does not look like a .zip file.';
    }

    if($_FILES['zip']['size']>104857600){
        $errors[] = 'There is a size limit of 100MB';
    }

    if($zip->open($_FILES['zip']['tmp_name'])==false){
        $errors[]='Failed to open zip file.';
    }

    if(empty($errors)){
        $extracted_files = array();

        for($i=0;$i<$zip->numFiles;$i++){
            $entry_info = $zip->statIndex($i);

            $extracted_files[] = $entry_info['name'];
        }

        print_r($extracted_files);

        $zip->extractTo('./uploads');
        $zip->close();
    }
}
```

That uploads the zip files and extracts them. Now i want to read the data from the .txt files and populate my database. The code below is what i have but i get errors, specifically for the path the files are in. If anyone could please help with the code i have below, as well help with the file path or suggest i put the files in another place. The code is the following:

```
$string = file_get_contents("set_1.txt","r");
$myFile = "/Applications/MAMP/bin/mamp/uploads";
$fh = fOpen($myFile,'w') or die("could not open: " . mysql_error());
fwrite($fh, $string);
fclose($fh);

$sql = mysql_connect("localhost", "root","root");
if(!$sql){
    die("could not connect: " . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("Tweet_Corpora");
$result = mysql_query("LOAD DATA INFILE '$myfile'" . " INTO TABLE Display FIELDS TERMINATED BY '/\s+/'");

if(!$result){
    die("could not load. " . mysql_error());
}
```

My table looks like this:

|id |tweet_id |raw_tweet |normalized_tweet|

I only need to fill in the columns tweet_id and raw_tweet

My data looks as follows in each of the files:

```
57587072533413889   @NAYDIVAA1 thought I saw u today u know
57743998223265792   The art of sleeping in the early morning and waking up at tea time.
57817604059959296   RT @dilleeeey: I'm very very very hungry. But I'm lazy to eat$
```

Please help. would really appreciate it.

Comment: Could you please share the exact error message you get?

Comment: 1st error:Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /Applications/MAMP/bin/mamp/home.php on line 12
2nd error:Warning: fopen(/Applications/MAMP/bin/mamp/uploads/): failed to open stream: Is a directory in /Applications/MAMP/bin/mamp/home.php on line 43
could not open:

Comment: What's line 12? The 2nd error points to the third line of your second code block. On the second line you define a directory instead of a file.

Comment: You extract to './uploads', but try & open "/Applications/MAMP/bin/mamp/uploads". Shouldn't the path be the same, and shouldn't you suffix it with the actual filename (extracted from ZIP) you're trying to open?

Comment: Unless this is something automated, it's much safer to do this with MySQL Workbench. Even then you can run a cron and do the insert command line without ever involving PHP.

Comment: line 12 refers to the following if statement on the 1st code block:

if(strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['zip']['name'])))!=='zip'){
        $errors[] = 'That does not look like a .zip file.';
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = file_get_contents("set_1.txt","r");
$myFile = "/Applications/MAMP/bin/mamp/uploads";
$fh = fOpen($myFile,'w') or die("could not open: " . mysql_error());
fwrite($fh, $string);
fclose($fh);
```

In this part, you read the file contents of a file which is, probably, in the root path, since you didn't define a path.

Next, you run fopen on a directory and to write something to it. That's not how it works. If you want to write something to a file, you should open the file. I don't even understand why you are trying to write to a file, while you already got a file with the contents. Even more weird, you show mysql_error() on the moment the file opening fails. Those 2 have nothing to do with eachother. You didn't even connect with the database.

I'm not familiar with the LOAD DATA INFILE, but probably your first part needs to look like this:

```
$string = file_get_contents("/path/to/file/set_1.txt","r");

$sql = mysql_connect("localhost", "root","root");
if(!$sql){
    die("could not connect: " . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("Tweet_Corpora");
$result = mysql_query("LOAD DATA INFILE '$myfile'" . " INTO TABLE Display FIELDS TERMINATED BY '/\s+/'");

if(!$result){
    die("could not load. " . mysql_error());
}
```

If you have big files, you maybe better use fopen and read only parts of the file. Maybe this question can help you out too:
[Read a text file and transfer contents to mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601349/read-a-text-file-and-transfer-contents-to-mysql-database)

Comment: I did the changes you suggested which has helped but now down one error:
Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /Applications/MAMP/bin/mamp/home.php on line 12

could not load. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't find you -___- lol 57587072533413889 @NAYDIVAA1 thought I saw u today u know 5' at line 1

Am struggling to understand what it means.