# Take words from text file and insert to database

Tags: php, sql, loops, text, insert

Let's say I have a text file called `words.txt` with 10 words, each word in a new line.

`word1
word2
word3
etc`

And I want to make a PHP script to read the text file and insert each word to an individual row by itself using MySQLi, how may I achieve such a thing? Thanks.

Comment: This question has been answered at least one thousand times. Please use Google to make sure a suitable answer does not exist before posting a question on stackoverflow.

Comment: The easiest way to achieve it is to start by writing some code.... [file()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) is a good function to start with

Comment: @TraianTatic I indeed did, but I didn't find anything that helps, some lack the new line, some lack reading from a text file, some lack the inserting, some didn't work for me and some weren't even PHP.

Comment: @Voiceeeeee Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601349/read-a-text-file-and-transfer-contents-to-mysql-database#2601383). And just FYI, I'm not the one who downvoted.

Comment: Sounds like a beginner assignment in a PHP class... College just started didn't it?

Comment: @jcalabris Nope, just a 15 years old teenager who does this as a hobby, and I don't know why I'm stuck here since I've done more complicated things but oh well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$link = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd")

$words = file('words.txt');

foreach($words as $word) {
    $link->query("INSERT INTO Words (Word) VALUES ({$word})"); 
}
```

This is by no means a robust solution but it should get you headed in the right direction...

Take note that file opens the entire file into memory. If this file is over 128MB it will throw an error. If this happens do not increase the the amount of memory php uses but switch to using fopen and reading in line by line.

Comment: I swear I tried something like this and it didn't work yet this did, thanks!

Comment: @Voiceeeeee if this is what you were looking for, accept his answer. Also, it should be `$words = file('words.txt');`.

Comment: @TraianTatic I was waiting for the timer to be over, and I noticed the quotations thing, tried to edit it but 6 chars while I only need  2.

Comment: @TraianTatic Thanks, added that in as well as the reason you should likely not use this.